# Tiling m by n rectangle game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, tiling

Consider an $m$ by $n$ rectangle. On this rectangle, two players take turns placing either $1$ by $2$ tiles or $3$ by $4$ tiles. The player who is able to place the last tile wins. Which player has a winning strategy and when?

Comment: $mn$ should be even, to even have a winner!

Comment: The player who is able to place the last tile wins.

Comment: Presumably that means if all the remaining gaps are isolated 1 by 1 squares, the next player loses.  This is not simple even ignoring the 3 by 4 tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Henry's comment, the game has a name and has been studied a bit, even without the option of placing $3\times4$ tiles. If you can only place dominoes, the game is called "[normal play]  [Cram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_%28game%29)".

Basically, [the general answer is not known, although we have a lot of results for particular small boards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_%28game%29#Known_values).